# Express, passport: can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm still a noob to node and webdev, but trying hard!
I get this error : can't set headers after they are sent

with the following while using passport.js and bcryptjs compare method for password validation on a mean stack

**routes/login.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var User = mongoose.model('User')
var passport = require('passport')

router.post('/', function (req, res, next){

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        if(user){  
              return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});    
        } else {     
              return res.status(401).send(info)   
        }

    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router
```

**authenticate/local.js**

```
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var User = mongoose.model('User')
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({
    username: username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err)
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: {
          username: 'Incorrect     username.'
        }
      })
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err)
      }
      if (!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: {
            password: 'Incorrect password'
          }
        })
      }
    });

    return done(null, user);
  });

}));
```

This validates correctly for a valid username and password, and logs in.

For an invalid username, it correctly rejects the login attempt.

But for an invalid password, it logs in and then crashes the app with the Can't set headers error.

However if i change the *bcrypt.compare* to *bcrypt.compareSync*, then all validations are correct.

```
if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
  return done(null, false, {
    message: {
      password: 'Incorrect password'
    }
  });
}
```

I would rather not depend on the sync methods, so help me please understand where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 3):

`bcrypt.compare()` is async but you're calling `done(null, user)` immediately. Move it inside the callback and it should be fine:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
  if (err) { return done(err) }
  if (!isMatch) {
    return done(null, false, { message: { password: 'Incorrect password' } })
  }
  done(null, user)
})
```

Comment: actually I'm just going to thank you again. You just helped me realise i didn't understand the basics of async, and now i do understand, that part of it anyway. so cheers!

Comment: Then you should mark this question as "answered", right? :)